# Variable Assignment plus an extra

Tags: java

```
boolean []r = new boolean[numberOfStates];
for(int i=0; i<numberOfStates;i++)
    r[i]=i==q;
```

Being q, i and numberOfStates int variables,
what does r[i]=i==q; do?

Comment: In a simpler design, this is the same as saying `boolean b = (1 == 1);` for example. `b` would be true in this sense.

Answer (score 3):

`i==q` resolves to a boolean, and is assigned as value to `r[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

It assigns true to `r[i]` if `i==q` and false if not.

Which means `r[q]` is the only element in the array that would be assigned true.

Since all the values of a boolean array are initialized to false, you can replace this code snippet with :

```
boolean [] r = new boolean[numberOfStates];
r[q] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you initialize array as and q as bellow you will end up with result

true 
false

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfStates = 2;
        int q = 0;
        boolean []r = new boolean[numberOfStates];
        r[0] = false;
        r[1] = false;
        for(int i=0; i<numberOfStates;i++)
            r[i]=i==q;

        for(int i=0; i<numberOfStates;i++)
            System.out.println(r[i]);

    }
```

as per my understanding == has higher Precedence than = 
so r[i]=i==q; will evaluated as i==q (q is 0) it result true
ans assigned to r[[0]] to true;